# file upload problem in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

[image]I browse my 54kb file in Magento, but still I can't upload my images and it doesn't show any error,how can I resolve it?

I tried with .png,.jpg as well.
I am trying to upload this .png image but after I click on upload file nothing happens.

Comment: can u upload screen shot so that we can guide u what exact problem u r facing?

Comment: where u would like to upload image?

Comment: check browser console for any errors & post them

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the Browser Adobe version or use chrome and try to upload it will be uploaded

Comment: I  am using latest version of adobe and i tried in chrome also but it won't work any other suggestion if u have